# What's the most memory efficient way to generate the combinations of a set in python?

Tags: python, performance, memory, combinatorics

This is the code I came up with:

```
def combinations(input):
    ret = ['']
    for i in range(len(input)):
        ret.extend([prefix+input[i] for prefix in ret])
    return ret
```

This algorithm is O(2^n) time, but can space be reduced? I heard using `yield` might work, but having trouble thinking through how to implement with `yield`. Please don't use the built in combination function -- I would like to see how it's implemented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question specifically said you wanted to see what the code would look like, so here is a hand coded example of an O(n) space solution:

```
def combinations(input_list, acc=''):

    if not input_list:
        yield acc
        return

    next_val = input_list[0]

    for rest in combinations(input_list[1:], acc):
        yield rest

    acc += next_val

    # In python 3.2, you can use "yield from combinations(input_list[1:], acc)"
    for rest in combinations(input_list[1:], acc):
        yield rest
```

Note that the substring arithmetic might be expensive (since it has to copy the string many times), so here is a slightly more efficient version in terms of complexity:

```
def combinations(input_list, acc='', from_idx=0):

    if len(input_list) <= from_idx:
        yield acc
        return

    next_val = input_list[from_idx]

    for rest in combinations(input_list, acc, from_idx + 1):
        yield rest

    acc += next_val

    # In python 3.2, you can use "yield from combinations(input_list[1:], acc)"
    for rest in combinations(input_list, acc, from_idx + 1):
        yield rest
```

I'm not using Python 3.2, but if you were you could write it like this:

```
def combinations(input_list, acc='', from_idx=0):

    if len(input_list) <= from_idx:
        yield acc
        return

    next_val = input_list[from_idx]

    yield from combinations(input_list, acc, from_idx + 1)
    acc += next_val
    yield from combinations(input_list, acc, from_idx + 1)
```

I should also note that this is purely academic since `itertools.combinations` does a fine job and works for a wider array of inputs (including generator expressions).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `yield` in your code like so:

```
def combinations(input):
    ret = ['']
    yield ''
    for i in range(len(input)):
        for prefix in ret:
             combination = prefix+input[i]
             ret.extend(combination)
             yield combination
```

But it doesn't save you any space.

The [itertools.combinations documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) shows a (much) more complicated algorithm that works in constant space - the [actual implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/bd353f12c007/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#l2266) is in C, but claims to be equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
>>> print list(itertools.combinations({1, 2, 3, 4}, 3))
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
>>>
```

Comment: -1 because the question asks specifically not to just use `itertools.combinations`.

Comment: above is an expensive operation. list conversion takes a lot of memory.